# Unix shell scripting — find and replace

Tags: regex, shell, unix, scripting

There are multiple files (1000 files) that need this change; doing it manually is not feasible — can anyone please suggest how to go about it in Unix/Linux shell scripting?

Requirement:

1. Wherever there is `l2cache[25-48]` for CONF_CATALOG_MULTI_SERVER_HOST_SECONDARY and CONF_SEARCH_MULTI_SERVER_HOST_SECONDARY, I need to change `[13-24]`.

   Example : `edc-v1-l2cache25` this changes to `edc-v1-l2cache13`, `edc-v1-l2cache26` changes to `edc-v1-l2cache14` and so on until 36 changes to 24 and removing the rest 37-48 .
2. Wherever there is `l2cache[1-24]` for CONF_SEARCH_MULTI_SERVER_HOST and CONF_CATALOG_MULTI_SERVER_HOST, I need to change to `[1-12]`
   i.e need to remove `l2cache[13-24]`, only `edc-v1-l2cache[1-12]` should be present in CONF_CATALOG_MULTI_SERVER_HOST and CONF_SEARCH_MULTI_SERVER_HOST

Example/INPUT data:

```
CONF_CATALOG_MULTI_SERVER_HOST_SECONDARY=edc-v1-l2cache25 ,edc-v1-l2cache26 ,edc-v1-l2cache27 ,edc-v1-l2cache28 ,edc-v1-l2cache29 ,edc-v1-l2cache30 ,edc-v1-l2cache31 ,edc-v1-l2cache32 ,edc-v1-l2cache33 ,edc-v1-l2cache34 ,edc-v1-l2cache35 ,edc-v1-l2cache36 ,edc-v1-l2cache37 ,edc-v1-l2cache38 ,edc-v1-l2cache39 ,edc-v1-l2cache40 ,edc-v1-l2cache41 ,edc-v1-l2cache42 ,edc-v1-l2cache43 ,edc-v1-l2cache44 ,edc-v1-l2cache45 ,edc-v1-l2cache46 ,edc-v1-l2cache47 ,edc-v1-l2cache48 
CONF_SEARCH_MULTI_SERVER_HOST_SECONDARY=edc-v1-l2cache25 ,edc-v1-l2cache26 ,edc-v1-l2cache27 ,edc-v1-l2cache28 ,edc-v1-l2cache29 ,edc-v1-l2cache30 ,edc-v1-l2cache31 ,edc-v1-l2cache32 ,edc-v1-l2cache33 ,edc-v1-l2cache34 ,edc-v1-l2cache35 ,edc-v1-l2cache36 ,edc-v1-l2cache37 ,edc-v1-l2cache38 ,edc-v1-l2cache39 ,edc-v1-l2cache40 ,edc-v1-l2cache41 ,edc-v1-l2cache42 ,edc-v1-l2cache43 ,edc-v1-l2cache44 ,edc-v1-l2cache45 ,edc-v1-l2cache46 ,edc-v1-l2cache47 ,edc-v1-l2cache48 
CONF_CATALOG_MULTI_SERVER_HOST=edc-v1-l2cache1 ,edc-v1-l2cache2 ,edc-v1-l2cache3 ,edc-v1-l2cache4 ,edc-v1-l2cache5 ,edc-v1-l2cache6 ,edc-v1-l2cache7 ,edc-v1-l2cache8 ,edc-v1-l2cache9 ,edc-v1-l2cache10 ,edc-v1-l2cache11 ,edc-v1-l2cache12 ,edc-v1-l2cache13 ,edc-v1-l2cache14 ,edc-v1-l2cache15 ,edc-v1-l2cache16 ,edc-v1-l2cache17 ,edc-v1-l2cache18 ,edc-v1-l2cache19 ,edc-v1-l2cache20 ,edc-v1-l2cache21 ,edc-v1-l2cache22 ,edc-v1-l2cache23 ,edc-v1-l2cache24 
CONF_SEARCH_MULTI_SERVER_HOST=edc-v1-l2cache1 ,edc-v1-l2cache2 ,edc-v1-l2cache3 ,edc-v1-l2cache4 ,edc-v1-l2cache5 ,edc-v1-l2cache6 ,edc-v1-l2cache7 ,edc-v1-l2cache8 ,edc-v1-l2cache9 ,edc-v1-l2cache10 ,edc-v1-l2cache11 ,edc-v1-l2cache12 ,edc-v1-l2cache13 ,edc-v1-l2cache14 ,edc-v1-l2cache15 ,edc-v1-l2cache16 ,edc-v1-l2cache17 ,edc-v1-l2cache18 ,edc-v1-l2cache19 ,edc-v1-l2cache20 ,edc-v1-l2cache21 ,edc-v1-l2cache22 ,edc-v1-l2cache23 ,edc-v1-l2cache24
```

OUTPUT data:

```
CONF_CATALOG_MULTI_SERVER_HOST_SECONDARY=edc-v1-l2cache13 ,edc-v1-l2cache14 ,edc-v1-l2cache15 ,edc-v1-l2cache16 ,edc-v1-l2cache17 ,edc-v1-l2cache18 ,edc-v1-l2cache19 ,edc-v1-l2cache20 ,edc-v1-l2cache21 ,edc-v1-l2cache22 ,edc-v1-l2cache23 ,edc-v1-l2cache24  
CONF_SEARCH_MULTI_SERVER_HOST_SECONDARY=edc-v1-l2cache13 ,edc-v1-l2cache14 ,edc-v1-l2cache15 ,edc-v1-l2cache16 ,edc-v1-l2cache17 ,edc-v1-l2cache18 ,edc-v1-l2cache19 ,edc-v1-l2cache20 ,edc-v1-l2cache21 ,edc-v1-l2cache22 ,edc-v1-l2cache23 ,edc-v1-l2cache24 
CONF_CATALOG_MULTI_SERVER_HOST=edc-v1-l2cache1 ,edc-v1-l2cache2 ,edc-v1-l2cache3 ,edc-v1-l2cache4 ,edc-v1-l2cache5 ,edc-v1-l2cache6 ,edc-v1-l2cache7 ,edc-v1-l2cache8 ,edc-v1-l2cache9 ,edc-v1-l2cache10 ,edc-v1-l2cache11 ,edc-v1-l2cache12  
CONF_SEARCH_MULTI_SERVER_HOST=edc-v1-l2cache1 ,edc-v1-l2cache2 ,edc-v1-l2cache3 ,edc-v1-l2cache4 ,edc-v1-l2cache5 ,edc-v1-l2cache6 ,edc-v1-l2cache7 ,edc-v1-l2cache8 ,edc-v1-l2cache9 ,edc-v1-l2cache10 ,edc-v1-l2cache11 ,edc-v1-l2cache12
```

Comment: `perl -pe 's/cache([0-9]+)/cache . ( $1 - 12 )/ge if m/CONF_CATALOG_MULTI/'` gets you most of the way there.  If you make the effort to reformat the question to be readable, someone might be willing to help more.  The above perl can easily be wrapped in a loop that will work on all the necessary inpu files, and you can add a `-i` option to change the files in place.  Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  What have you tried, and where did you run into trouble?  Also, while you've shown some sample input data, you've not shown the desired output — that is always helpful.  Also, you say 'CSMSH _and_ CCMSH' but no line of data has both; do you mean 'or' rather than 'and'?

Comment: For bullet 1, how are you supposed to squish the 24 values in the range 25-48 into the 12 values in the range 13-24?

Answer (score 1):

So, those names are diabolically long!

Judging from the output, for the CSMSHS and CCMSHS entries, you need to change things so that entries with 25-48 are reorganized so that there are  12 entries with values 13-24 and the other 12 entries are deleted.

Similarly, for the CSMSH and CCMSH entries, you want to delete the entries with values 13-24.

Presumably you don't have to worry about erratic entries in the files; they are all consistent at the moment, and should all be consistent afterwards.

Frankly, the simplest thing is to create the replacement string and use a relatively simple search to identify the lines that need to be changed (ensuring that the changes are idempotent; reapplying the script to a converted file won't change the file a second time).  I find the space-comma notation off-putting; in the circles I work in, that should be comma-space.  However, we can leave that alone.

I'd use Perl, but Awk could be used if you wanted to, and Python likewise would do the job handily.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $base = "edc-v1-l2cache";
my $secondary = "";
my $pad = "";
for (my $i = 13; $i <= 24; $i++)
{
     $secondary .= $pad . $base . $i;
     $pad = " ,";   # ", "!
}
my $primary = "";
$pad = "";
for (my $i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++)
{
     $primary .= $pad . $base . $i;
     $pad = " ,";   # ", "!
}

while (<>)
{
    s//$1$secondary/
        if (m/(CONF_(?:CATALOG|SEARCH)_MULTI_SERVER_HOST_SECONDARY=)${base}25 ,.*${base}48$/);
    s//$1$primary/
        if (m/(CONF_(?:CATALOG|SEARCH)_MULTI_SERVER_HOST=)${base}1 ,.*${base}24$/);
    print;
}
```

If some of the entries might be missing and that needs to be treated specially, you have to work a lot harder.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, actually wanted in bash shellscript environment, really appreciate you effort though.

Comment: That is a script that can be run by Bash.  If you want to do it in Bash, transliterate the loops and apply `sed` instead.  Or use Awk instead of Perl.  And if you can't use anything except Bash (so even `sed` is out), then you've been assigned a crackpot assignment.  Perl _is_ a tool for use from Bash scripts, just like `sed` and `awk` are.

Comment: Yes ,awk and sed can be used, i'm beginner in scripting, this just fell into my kit

Comment: If there isn't a formal constraint "thou shalt not use Perl" then use Perl.  If there's a formal constraint "thou shalt not do the edit with Perl", can you use Perl to generate the `sed` script?  Basically, you are throwing rocks into your own path if you don't use Perl or Python (or Ruby, or …) for this.  It can be done in Awk; it will be painful to code it in Awk.  It can be done with Bash creating a `sed` script; it will be painful to code that, too.  It was bad enough doing the Perl. I'm off to sleep; you'll have to hope someone else is kind enough to help you through your obstacle course.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for your help

Comment: Jonathan , one last thing ,how do i process a or multiple files with this script

Comment: Do you want to overwrite the originals?  If so: `perl -i.bak thescript.pl *.cfg` or whatever.  The `-i.bak` preserves the original with the `.bak` extension (so `file000.cfg` is copied to `file000.cfg.bak`) and the edited copy is in place.  Otherwise, just `perl thescript.pl *.cfg` will process them all.  If you're a braver man than I, you can omit the `.bak` and Perl will simply edit the files in situ.  That option alone is a reason for using Perl.